# How to share laptop wired internet with android 6 smartphone using ubuntu 14 wifi

Tags: wireless

How to share laptop wired internet with android 6 smartphone using ubuntu 14 wifi

Answer (score -1):

You can use a package named [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) to do it. Check the link for documentation.

Comment: whoever marked downvoted my question please explain